# Outputting the name of a function as it's called?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have 80 or so phpunit tests, is it possible that, when a functions is called, I can some how output the function name for each test? I know I can manually do it but I was hoping there might be a hook that gets called with every function call that could assist me (or something similar).

edit: every tester method

Comment: Every testER function (method) or testED function?

Answer (score 2):

**Intro:**

For functions you would use [`__FUNCTION__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) (linked) and for class methods you can use [`__METHOD__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) (linked).

**Function:**

```
function my_function() {
    echo __FUNCTION__;
}
```

Output would be `my_function`;

**Class Method:**

```
class Treffynnon {
    public function my_method() {
        echo __METHOD__;
    }
}
```

Output would be `my_method`;

**Display a function as it was called:**

```
function my_function($param1, $param2, $param3) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    echo __FUNCTION__ . '(' . implode(', ', $args) . ')';
}
my_function('blah', 'blah', 'blah');
```

Output would be `my_function(blah, blah, blah);`. Obviously this could be improved immensely to more accurately represent how the arguments were passed (ie. quoting the params that are output).

See [func_get_args() man page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

- If you want to display **the name of each function called by your test**, the answer is **No, there is no way**. Except of course by adding code in those functions, as described in the other answers.

PHP doesn't provide a way to have a "hook" called before any function is called.

- If you want to display **the name of each test function** (in your test class) when it's called, then that's another thing.

First you can add parameters to your phpunit call :

```
phpunit --verbose tests/
phpunit --testdox tests/
```

Or if that's not enough, you can use the [setUp()](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html#fixtures.more-setup-than-teardown) function, that is executed before **each** test, to display the test currently being run.

Comment: I like your thinking on this too. Doing it in the `setUp()` method is a nice alternative.

Comment: what variable/method is available to setup? this is a preferable method but i was unaware of how to do it.

Comment: @tipu - You can use `$this->getName()`, but I wonder why you wouldn't just use the `--verbose` or `--debug` flags when running PHPUnit. Doing any output in `setUp()` may cause problems with tools that call PHPUnit such as your IDE or build server. Better to use the command-line flag only when you need to see the test method names.

Comment: Yes @David is right the best method is simply to use "phpunit --testdox YourTest.php".

Comment: I just tried `--verbose` and was reminded why I don't use it: it doesn't really do anything different. `--testdox` has very nice output and `--debug` is great if you are debugging issues with your testing framework such as base test case classes.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the method name of you test case can be retrieved via `getName()` method. It accepts  an optional argument for retrieving current data input for the test method.

You can find example of its usage in this section of PHPUnit documentation: 
http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener

Comment: Good call. I had forgotten about that one. Have been working on untested legacy code for too long!